# Keep the log files data between a week and delete rest of the data

Tags: shell-script

I have 6 to 8 log files which contains date and timestamp  in this format 
**INFO [07-29 04:13:03.795] (blah.blah)** I want to Keep the log files data between last Monday to Sunday and delete rest of the data from those log files using bash script

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like `for date in 09-{05..11} ; do grep \\[$date logfile > $date.log ; done` to split the desired days' logs into their own files, but you should really be using the `logrotate` utility to manage that for you.

Comment: This is giving me error like below and log files getting created but with 0 bytes of data
egrep: Unmatched [ or [^
egrep: Unmatched [ or [^
egrep: Unmatched [ or [^
egrep: Unmatched [ or [^
egrep: Unmatched [ or [^
egrep: Unmatched [ or [^
egrep: Unmatched [ or [^

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have enough escapes. I've updated with a corrected command.

Comment: Thank you for the correction ,now its not throwing any errors but it wont generate any output either . i am looking for something like  awk or sed to compare with the filed values in log file anbd  if the value is not within in the time range delete and save the file